i am trying to get an effect on a span element in my homepage but using hover on the span element does not do anything
import styled from "styled-components";

const Header = (props) => {
return <Nav>
    <Logo>
        <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Disney+" />
    </Logo>
    <NavMenu>
        <a href="/home">
            <img src="/images/home-icon.svg" alt="HOME" />
            <span>HOME</span>
        </a>         
    </NavMenu>
    </Nav>;
}

const Nav = styled.nav`
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 70px;
background-color: #090b13;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
padding: 0 36px;
letter-spacing: 16px;
z-index: 3px;
`;

const Logo = styled.a`
padding: 0;
width: 80px;
margin-top: 4px;
max-height: 70px;
font-size: 0;
display: inline-block;

img{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
`;

const NavMenu = styled.div`
align-items: center;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
height: 100%;
justify-content: flex-end;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: 25px;


a {     
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 12px;
        
    img {
        height: 20px;
        min-width: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        z-index: auto;
   }

   span {
        color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
        font-size: 13px;
        letter-spacing: 1.42px;
        line-height: 1.08;
        padding: 2px 0px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: relative; 
      
       
   &:before {
        background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
        border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
        bottom: -6px;
        content: "";
        height: 2px;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        transform-origin: left center;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0s;
        visibility: hidden;
        width: auto;
    } 
}  

 &:hover {
        &span:before {
            transform: scaleX(1);
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }
    }
       
}    
`;


export default Header;

i have tried to rearrange the hover code thinking it would help that maybe its in the wrong place but to no avail, other things i have tried is actually commenting out the hover command and tweaking things in a:before and they seem to work fine but when i try to add the hover effect to the span element, nothing happens, i will really appreciate if somebody can help out with this problem.Thank you.your text
